# Rudin's PMA 10.31, regarding ambuiguity of boundary of simplices under $C^1$ map

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, differential-geometry, differential-forms

[image]

I tried to come up with proofs ($1st, 2$nd$ proofs are deleted) but got stuck in some point.

Seeing all problems, I come up with the third proof.

Let $f=T_2^{-1}T_1$, let $Q^n$ be the standard simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\sigma_0$ be the standard positively oriented n-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$, now $f(Q^n)=Q^n$.

Proof ($3$rd):

$f$ is a diffeomorphism on $Q^n$. Since $f$ is diffeomorphism, the topological boundary of $Q^n$ is mapped to itself.

Now it is defined that $\partial f=f(\partial \sigma_0)$ is the positively oriented boundary.

Since jacobian of $f$ $\gt 0$, $f(\sigma_0)$ have same orientation as $\sigma_0$, $f$ preserves orientation also on its boundary. Hence $\partial f= \partial \sigma_0$.

Edit: All previous proofs are deleted as I thought they are either erroneous or a rephrase of the $3$rd proof. Turn out, the question that remains is the consistency of all definition of orientation used, but that only means studies of differential geometry awaits.

Status: For proof verification.

Comment: Since $f$ preserves orientation on the simplex (because the jacobian of $f$ is positive), it induces the same boundary orientation on the boundary of the simplex.

Comment: Thanks! I think I just get the solution.